# Angular2 - Attaching angular event handler to a dynamically created DOM element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I understand that what I'm trying to accomplish is extremely ugly, but I'm hoping there is still a way to do that:

```
public test(id: any): void{
    alert(id);
}

constructor(private _appService: AppService) {    
        var self = this;

        var popup = new InfoTemplate();
        popup.setContent(graphic => {
            return "<a (click)=\"test(" + graphic.attributes.id + ")\">Details</a>";
        });
}
```

In words: I would like to dynamically create a link within a third party components element, which has a angular function `test()` as the `onClick` event handler.

Is there any way to do that in Angular2 RC6?

Comment: Have you just tried normal `document.getElementBy...` functions to access the element and attach to whatever events you need? If you have access to the DOM element for `InfoTemplate`, you should be able to find the link you added.